# Symfony 4: problem trying to update login form authenticator generated by makerBundle, RuntimeException about csrfToken

Tags: symfony4, csrf-token

I have a project that started some time ago with Symfony 4. And I had login files generated from the `php bin/console make:auth`command. Today I saw that the file information have changed a bit in the newer document so I wanted to update mine. I ran the same command again, renamed the new controller and authentication file. But when I tried it out, I got this error:

> Cannot autowire service "App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator": argument "$csrfTokenManager" of method "__construct()" references interface "Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface" but no such service exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?

What does it mean?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. You must enable the csrf protection in config/packages/framework.yaml:

```
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    csrf_protection: false #change this to true
```